# Using Services, why is the resource name appended to the endpoint?

Tags: uri, services, 8

If I want an operation of GET `api/v1.0/users` and `api/v1.0/pages`:

Using the Services module to create a REST API, if I define a service with an endpoint of `api/v1.0/users` and enable the `user` resource (let's say I enable the Retrieve action), then I have to go to the URI `/api/v1.0/users/user/` to get it to work. If I don't include the `/user` at the end, it returns a 404 error.

However, if I make the endpoint simply `api/v1.0`, and enable the same resources, then the URI is closer to expect and want: `/api/v1.0/user/`, but still not quite right. Also, If I define other endpoints using this style (eg. for `/api/v1.0/node/`), only the last one works; the rest return a 404 error.

Why is it designed this way? And how can I make it not append the resource name to the end?

---

**Update**: Based on @mradcliffe's answer, it seems that it's been designed this way so that you can define a single endpoint as a sort of 'endpoint base', such as `api/v1.0`, then enable multiple resources, which then append their names to the endpoint path.

The problem I see with that is that, if I later create a new version of a resource (eg. the user resource) that does things a little differently, and I thus want to name it with a new version number (eg. users_1.1) to distinguish it from the old resource, that would create a horrible endpoint path of `api/v1.1/users_1.1`...?

---

**Update**: To answer the question of my previous update, I think a better (more efficient) programming practice would be to simply check the api version within the code (wherever the new code deviates from the old) rather than re-naming the resource. I could define a function that pulls the version out of the path for this checking.

Comment: I think that this question is very subjective. Services is designed to create one or more unique endpoints where each endpoint is a collection of resources. This is the way it works. If you want an endpoint for your v1.0 API, then you make it `/api/1.0` and enable the node and user resources. If you want an endpoint for your v1.1 API, then you create a new endpoint `/api/1.1` and enable the node and user resources. Perhaps it is unclear what you are asking? Why do you want an endpoint that is `/api/v1.0/users` specifically?

Comment: Thank you @mradcliffe, you've actually answered my question here in your comment; "why is it done this way"? I was confusing the concept of an enpoint. If you make it an answer, I will vote this one as correct, since it answers my main question.

Answer (score 3):

See mradcliffe's comment for a good explanation of the difference between an endpoint and a resource, understanding that will make it clear why the Services module does things the way it does.

Why is the endpoint for the user entity type specifically named `user`?

Conceptually speaking it's a safe bet that the module developer followed common REST patterns, and adopted the name of the entity as defined by the system the code is sitting in (i.e. the `user` entity type defined by Drupal core).

From a technical point of view, the resource is named `user` because the services module explicitly names it as such in [`_user_resource_definition()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!services!resources!user_resource.inc/function/_user_resource_definition/7):

```
$definition = array(
    'user' => array(
      'operations' => array(
        ...
```

Not a fan of this particular convention? Not a problem, Services has you covered.

Go to the "Edit Resources" tab for your endpoint, and look in the right hand column of the table; you'll see a text field that takes an "Alias". Set that to "users" for the User resource.

Set your endpoint to something sensible like 'api/v1.0', and you can now access the `user` resource through its alias at http://example.com/api/v1.0/users. It sounds like you might also want to add a "pages" alias for the "Node" resource, but I'm speculating a bit.